# Linked server performace issue?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, performance, trigger, linked-server

I have created a linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition for MySQL i.e. MySQL database is accessible under SQL Server environment. I have a created a trigger in SQL Server such that every new entry in the SQL Server object(table) also insert a new entry in the MySQL database object.

The issue here occurs with performance, that is without trigger insert in SQL Server is fast but when trigger is created the insert becomes very flow. The performance is degraded too much.

Please help me how to optimize the performance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257326/slow-queries-when-using-mysql-as-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-odbc-connectio

Comment: Thanks but the same issue is with me as I am using **INSERT OPENQUERY(MYSQL,'select * from tbl limit 0') select top 1 * from dbo.tbl order by id desc** . Any suugestion on this??

Comment: Please have a look at this article: SQL Server linked server performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248753/sql-server-linked-server-performance. Do you really need to update the MySQL database right away or is some delay acceptable? Do you know if you have a lot of inserts in this table?

Comment: Service Broker could be your friend if some delay is allowed. Under normal circumnstances, the delay can be very short.